# MySQL subquery not working

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Please, can you review this query? I can't retrieve the correct values with the sub-query. I believe my logic is incorrect.

I'm trying to make this work day after day, but without success.

Above the SQL query in the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7b2/9) has the comments to reproduce the error.

With this [sketch](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif) you can have a better understanding of what I need.

```
SELECT P.nome, centroide_produto_id, similar_produto_id, 
       (SELECT preco_venda FROM precos A
        WHERE A.produto_id = CL.similar_produto_id 
          AND A.preco_id = (SELECT Max(preco_id)
                            FROM precos A2,
                                 cluster_copy3 CL2
                            WHERE A2.produto_id = A.produto_id
                              AND A2.produto_id=CL2.similar_produto_id
                              AND A2.preco_venda = (SELECT Max(preco_venda)
                                                    FROM precos A3,
                                                         cluster_copy3 CL3
                                                    WHERE A3.produto_id = CL3.similar_produto_id
                                                      AND CL3.centroide_produto_id = CL.centroide_produto_id))) AS preco_maximo
FROM produtos P,
     cluster_copy3 CL
WHERE P.produto_id = CL.centroide_produto_id 
AND CL.centroide_produto_id IN (9817, 9816)
#GROUP BY CL.centroide_produto_id
```

Comment: and is a product always similar to itself?

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what you want to do, there is a simpler query that would accomplish it.  Simple sample data and desired results (in the question) would help.

Comment: and there seems to be some confusion about whether you want the highest price, or the most recent price

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you for you reply! I will write some more explanation tonight, because unfortunately I'm without time right now :-/

Comment: What I need is this: in SQLfiddle, comment the line 14 and run the query. The preco_maximo returned are: 169, 243, 149 and 100. With MAX(preco_id) and MAX(preco_venda) the correct prices I need are: 243 for centroide 9816 and 149 for centroide 9817

Comment: Please see this [sketch](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif)

Comment: A better explanation: please see this new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7b2/9) with this new [sketch](http://sencial.me/images/esquema_sql_preco.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this, getting the data in a subquery and grouping in the main query.

```
    SELECT
    t.nome,
    t.centroide_produto_id,
    t.similar_produto_id,
    MAX(t.preco_maximo)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            P.nome,
            centroide_produto_id,
            similar_produto_id,
            (
                SELECT
                    preco_venda
                FROM
                    precos A
                INNER JOIN cluster_copy3 CL2 ON A.produto_id = CL2.similar_produto_id
                WHERE
                    A.produto_id = P.produto_id
                ORDER BY
                    A.preco_id DESC,
                    A.preco_venda DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS preco_maximo
        FROM
            produtos P,
            cluster_copy3 CL
        WHERE
            P.produto_id = CL.similar_produto_id
        AND CL.centroide_produto_id IN (9817, 9816)
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
    t.centroide_produto_id
```